# How to connect vitess in multi region kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes-vitess

I have two clusters on GKE. Each cluster has a 6 node setup. I just deployed a helm chart of vitess on both clusters.

A vitess operator is also deployed. etcd deplyoed with `clusterWide: true`

My question is how to connect these two seperate vitess deployment so they work as one like this demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Hz6LFJu1cY

Comment: what have you done so far???

Comment: 2 cluster(running indifferent region) are connected by the [submariner](https://github.com/submariner-io/submariner). then deployed vitess in both cluster

Comment: Connecting two kubernetes clusters is an orthogonal problem, and there are many solutions. Once you get the two clusters talking to each other, Vitess should be able to leverage that automatically.

Comment: @SuguSougoumarane I am successfully able to run vitess in a single cluster using helm chart and my both clusters are able to talk each other but if i need to deploy it once in cluster then I am confused how to handle vitess config when we need to run it in multi region. our use case is similar to [Geo-partitioning with Vitess](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Hz6LFJu1cY).

Comment: @SuguSougoumarane do you have any resources for multi region (Any documentaion)

Comment: @Professor Here's a demo that shows a multi-kubernets cluster deployment of vitess. Maybe this will help https://youtu.be/OZl4HrB9p-8